Chrome debugger shows Indexeddb quota is "0 B"
When I open Chrome devtools and go to Application -> Storage -> IndexedDB -> (My app) it tells me the Quota is 0 B.
But if I type in await navigator.storage.estimate(); into the console I get:
quota: 296630877388

Can anyone tell me why the Quota in the Application tab is showing as 0B?

